# How to detect console error in Javascript (due to syntax error)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to detect when a console error occurs. I've looked here and have seen 2 suggestions

`window.onerror`
and
`try catch`

The following demonstrates an issue where this is not "caught" (by caught, as per the code below, I'd expect to see an `alert` and I do not).

```
window.onerror = function(error) {
    alert("window error..." + error );
}

    const arr = [];

try{
    arr.push({
        'firstValue':'Me 'And' You',
        'otherValue':5
    });
}catch(err){
    alert("Error..." + err);
}
```

The part causing the issue is

```
'firstValue':'Me 'And' You',
```

The reason for this is how this line of code is generated and I suspect the real fix is to correct this (using MVC.NET Razor)

```
'firstValue': '@Model.MyStringWithNoFormattingOrChecking'
```

Where the value of `MyStringWithNoFormattingOrChecking` is `Me 'And' You`

However, my question is about why the `onerror` or `try catch` didn't work. Or what I could have done to have caught this using javascript (I don't actually show an alert, I log via Ajax)

Comment: Syntax errors are not catched at runtime, since a code having a syntax error is never executed.

Comment: I don't think you can catch plain syntax errors like that with javascript. The parser will stop after the `'Me '`

Comment: @baao, if I'm using the wrong tool/tech, then that is fine. What could I use instead of JavaScript then?

Comment: @Teemu, understood, that makes sense actually. But what can I do to catch this then as this issue only comes up when the page is rendered?

Comment: You need to properly escape the `'` within the string. I've never used MVC.NET, so I can't say how to fix the creation of the string - but I'd look there first instead of on the js part

Comment: Fix : catch(Exception error)

Comment: This is indeed an escaping issue within .NET rather than a JavaScript error handling issue.  [This article](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) is an excellent summary of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `onerror` code in its own script tag, which runs earlier than this syntax error.

This code does what you want

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.onerror = function(error) {
    alert("window error..." + error );
}
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
const arr = [];

try{
    arr.push({
        'firstValue':'Me 'And' You',
        'otherValue':5
    });
}catch(err){
    alert("Error..." + err);
}
    </script>

</head>
```

[tested in Firefox, Chome and Edge]